# How to get a div (a text box) to stick to a certain point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am quite new to this, so I do not know if I have something that clashes with each other.

But I want the "textbox" to be stuck to the position under the navbar, and that it is scrollable when the information within exceeds the screen size. I also do not want the box to move when the screen gets resized, I just want the text to get smaller, like using a min-width.

I have a bit of JavaScript connected to this website too, but I do not know if it's needed to include it.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.background {
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom left,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)
    ),
    url(./Revendreth111.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 1600px;
  background-size: cover cover;
  overflow: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

li {
  /* float: right; */
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(87, 87, 87);
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}
a:hover {
  color: #800a0a;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.active {
  background-color: #610707;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul.navbar li.right,
  ul.topnav li {
    float: none;
  }
}

/* Textbox */
.text-box {
  background: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.555);
  color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
  margin-top: -80%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 150%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  /* text-align: center; */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0.2rem 0.9rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418));
  backdrop-filter: blur(0.11rem);
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /* top: 0px; */
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 40%;
}
.paragraph {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  margin-left: 3%;
}

#logo {
  width: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  /* Adjust these values accordingly */
  top: 18px;
  left: 5px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed/sticky position */
  bottom: 20px; /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
  right: 30px; /* Place the button 30px from the right */
  z-index: 99; /* Make sure it does not overlap */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  outline: none; /* Remove outline */
  background-color: rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.568); /* Set a background color */
  color: white; /* Text color */
  cursor: pointer; /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
  padding: 15px; /* Some padding */
  border-radius: 50%; /* Rounded corners */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font size */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0.2rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377));
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #0e0e0e69; /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0.2rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377));
}

/* Scroll bar customization */
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f100;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.911);
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.171);
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Test1.css" />
    <title>PLACE HOLDER / DRAENOR-EU</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="navbar">
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">progress</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">apply</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="text-box">
          <div class="row">
<div class="column"><h1><img  src="./logo.png" alt="" id="logo"> Welcome to Place Holder</h1>
        <p class="paragraph">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima non aspernatur ab architecto asperiores nemo odit dolorum explicabo autem eaque hic deserunt facere impedit maiores debitis obcaecati quibusdam vel et eveniet blanditiis recusandae nihil, modi earum odio? Repellendus dolorem atque dolor quisquam, fugit et ipsa. Dolorem facilis totam dolore aliquam.
</p>
<p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis repellat minus quas. Debitis explicabo, laborum quasi at facilis assumenda alias itaque eum! Maiores dolores neque mollitia odit nulla cumque, illum cum reiciendis deserunt eveniet! Est beatae architecto, minus, aut, alias soluta tempore quos numquam quod accusantium quidem corrupti ex suscipit?</p></div>
  <div class="column" id="sidebar"><h2>RECRUITMENT</h2>
        <p class="paragraph">Temporibus sed, quidem quo amet animi explicabo beatae illo aperiam numquam asperiores.</p></div> 
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="footer">
      Copyright © Place Holder 2021. All rights reserved.
      <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">▲</button>
    </div>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
  </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./test1.js"></script>
```

Comment: use `@media` for responsive design

Comment: Please provide us with a [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It is updated now :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure but....
Try using
Width="" or height=""

(IN SIDE THE DIV BLOCK)

{not verified to work}

Also! welcome to stackoverflow NEW MEMBER!

Comment: I used width and height but in percentages. may this be why it is messing up? Thank you by the way!

Comment: No, I tried changing the width and height to px, but it doesn't change it. I also commented out the navbar to see if it changed the outcome, but it does the same...